How to create a sample graphql code in Python?
I'm trying to create a small sample GraphQL code in python, but it is failing.
>>> from graphql import graphql_sync, build_schema
>>> schema = build_schema('''  type Query { hello: String } ''')
>>> def resolve_hello(parent, info):
...     return 'Hello World!'
...
>>> root_value = {'hello': resolve_hello}
>>> query = '{hello}'
>>> result = graphql_sync(schema, query, root_value=root_value)
>>> result
ExecutionResult(data={'hello': None}, errors=[GraphQLError("resolve_hello() missing 1 required positional argument: 'info'", locations=[SourceLocation(line=1, column=2)], path=['hello'])])


What is failing? what are you trying here?
